# Remove a prefix if matches an entry on a list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings with some prefixes:

```
prefixes = [u'path', u'folder', u'directory', u'd']
```

and some strings like

```
s1 = u'path common path and directory'
s2 = u'directory common path and directory'
s3 = u'directory folder distinct and directory folder'
s4 = u'distinct and directory folder'
s5 = u'd fixable directory or folder'
```

and I need to remove only the prefixes that matches one in the list:

```
# after processing
s1 = u'common path and directory'
s2 = u'common path and directory'
s3 = u'folder distinct and directory folder'
s4 = u'distinct and directory folder'
s5 = u'fixable directory or folder'
```

I tried using

```
''.join([word for word in s1.split() if word not in prefixes])
```

or

```
for prefix in prefixes:
    if s1.startswith(prefix):
       return s1[len(prefix):]
```

but this will remove the prefixes anywhere in the string or will not match the entire word (notice that I have a `d` there and this would match `directory`, giving only `irectory`), not only in the beginning. Is there a way to do it without using regex?

Comment: It seems like you want to split by spaces to consider whole words, but only when checking the prefix. (Which isn't really a prefix then, more of a "leading word".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to search for whole words they will be terminated by a  space character. I suggest you append it to the prefix:

```
prefixes = [u'path', u'folder', u'directory', u'd']

mystrings = [u'path common path and directory', u'directory common path and directory', u'directory folder distinct and directory folder', u'distinct and directory folder', u'd fixable directory or folder']
for s in mystrings:
    for prefix in prefixes: 
        if s.startswith(prefix+" "): 
            print s[len(prefix)+1:]
```

## Demo

```
>>> 
common path and directory
common path and directory
folder distinct and directory folder
fixable directory or folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split by `" "` to get the first word, and remove it if it's in the prefix list.

```
firstWord=s1.split(" ")[0]
if firstWord in prefixes:
   s1=" ".join(s1.split(" ")[1:])
```

You can also split on all whitespace with `split()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `partition` or `split` with limit they're great for this.

```
prefixes = [u'path', u'folder', u'directory', u'd']
strings = [u'path common path and directory',
           u'directory common path and directory'
           u'directory folder distinct and directory folder',
           u'distinct and directory folder',
           u'd fixable directory or folder']
```

partition returns a tuple of 3 items containing head, sep and tail. The head is everything before the delimiter, the sep is the delimiter separating the string at and tail is everything after. Indexing it with [2] only grabs the tail.

```
res = []
for s in strings:
    s2 = s.partition(' ')
    if s2[0] in prefixes:
        res.append(s2[2])
    else:
        res.append(s)
print(res)

#List comp
print([s.partition(' ')[2] if s.partition(' ')[0] in prefixes else s for s in strings])

#Output for s1 | (head, sep, tail)
[0] | "path"
[1] | " "
[2] | "common path and directory"
```

Split with a limit generates a list where it splits at the delimiter only the number of times specified, everything left over is then added. So with a limit of 1 then length is always at most 2.

```
res = []
for s in strings:
    s2 = s.split(' ', 1)
    if s2[0] in prefixes:
        res.append(s2[1])
    else:
        res.append(s)
print(res)

#List comp
print([s.split(' ', 1)[1] if s.split(' ', 1)[0] in prefixes else s for s in strings])

#Output for s1 | [first item, everything else]
[0] | "path"
[1] | "common path and directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
def func(s):                          
    pr = s.split()[0]
    if pr in prefixes:
        return ' '.join(s2.split()[1:])
```

This takes the first word and sees whether it is present in `prefixes` or not. If it is, it removes the word.